# Bash - Sort the keys of an associative array in-memory in ascending order?

Tags: bash, sorting, associative-array

This Bash function is part of a script that i've recently wrote (following below is a minimal working example of the script with sample data, including an invocation of the function):

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A result

stopSchedule='[{"stopId":41571,"lineId":1,"routeId":28,"remainingTime":[3450,8970,13170]},{"stopId":41571,"lineId":2,"routeId":29,"remainingTime":[1410,7950,12750]},{"stopId":41571,"lineId":2,"routeId":30,"remainingTime":[3030,9570,14370]},{"stopId":41571,"lineId":13,"routeId":36,"remainingTime":[3210,7410]},{"stopId":41571,"lineId":6,"routeId":39,"remainingTime":[3090,8790,13110]},{"stopId":41571,"lineId":8,"routeId":43,"remainingTime":[524,4590,9030]},{"stopId":41571,"lineId":8,"routeId":44,"remainingTime":[2190,6150,10590]},{"stopId":41571,"lineId":12,"routeId":52,"remainingTime":[1590]},{"stopId":41571,"lineId":10,"routeId":54,"remainingTime":[2970]}]'
stopsData='[{"id":41571,"areaId":1,"number":"44","name":"МБАЛ Добрич","translations":{},"lat":43.56184005737305,"lon":27.818910598754883,"note":""}]'
routesData='[{"id":44,"lineId":8,"direction":"Практикер-Депо","name":"Практикер-Депо","begin":1682629200,"end":0,"length":9876,"stopIds":[41674,41822,41630,41747,41750,41806,41681,41718,41745,41552,41576,41571,41731,41589,41627,41802,41643,41590,41625,41600,41694,41604,41676,41579,41654,41641,41595],"stopOffsets":[0,120,180,240,300,360,480,540,600,660,720,780,840,900,960,1020,1080,1140,1260,1320,1380,1440,1500,1560,1620,1680,1740]},{"id":43,"lineId":8,"direction":"Депо-Практикер","name":"Депо-Практикер","begin":1682629200,"end":0,"length":10076,"stopIds":[41595,41641,41655,41578,41675,41603,41695,41624,41591,41642,41803,41626,41588,41602,41571,41658,41746,41717,41682,41807,41749,41748,41724,41631,41629,41674],"stopOffsets":[0,60,120,180,240,300,360,420,480,540,600,660,720,780,900,960,1020,1080,1140,1260,1320,1380,1440,1500,1560,1680]},{"id":39,"lineId":6,"direction":"Балик-Дружба-Център","name":"Балик-Дружба-Център","begin":1682629200,"end":0,"length":10237,"stopIds":[41688,41689,41710,41559,41686,41791,41567,41703,41636,41743,41612,41613,41617,41529,41615,41548,41805,41681,41665,41773,41576,41571,41658,41623,41764,41627,41802],"stopOffsets":[0,60,120,180,300,360,480,540,660,720,840,900,960,1080,1140,1200,1260,1320,1380,1440,1500,1560,1620,1740,1800,1860,1920]},{"id":29,"lineId":2,"direction":"Балик-Старт","name":"Балик-Старт","begin":1682542801,"end":0,"length":11100,"stopIds":[41688,41689,41710,41786,41559,41686,41693,41634,41565,41632,41795,41793,41536,41652,41821,41619,41681,41718,41745,41552,41576,41571,41731,41589,41627,41767,41734,41684,41692],"stopOffsets":[0,60,120,180,300,360,480,540,600,720,780,840,900,960,1020,1140,1260,1380,1440,1500,1620,1680,1740,1800,1860,1980,2040,2100,2160]},{"id":28,"lineId":1,"direction":"АПК-Строител","name":"АПК-Строител","begin":1682542801,"end":0,"length":9655,"stopIds":[41687,41545,41719,41580,41645,41647,41571,41658,41746,41717,41682,41608,41701,41811,41582,41728,41649,41594,41787,41711,41568,41754,41792,41910,41693],"stopOffsets":[0,60,180,300,360,420,540,600,660,780,840,900,960,1020,1080,1140,1200,1260,1320,1380,1440,1560,1620,1681,1740]},{"id":30,"lineId":2,"direction":"Старт-Балик","name":"Старт-Балик","begin":1682542801,"end":0,"length":11140,"stopIds":[41692,41683,41733,41768,41626,41588,41602,41571,41658,41746,41717,41682,41620,41666,41653,41537,41794,41796,41633,41912,41910,41693,41685,41787,41711,41688],"stopOffsets":[0,60,120,180,300,360,420,540,600,660,720,780,900,960,1080,1140,1200,1320,1380,1500,1560,1620,1740,1860,1920,1980]},{"id":52,"lineId":12,"direction":"Липите-Център","name":"Липите-Център","begin":1682629200,"end":0,"length":7705,"stopIds":[41669,41677,41679,41722,41551,41660,41799,41698,41818,41671,41605,41781,41576,41571,41658,41746,41717,41682,41608,41701,41811,41716],"stopOffsets":[0,120,180,300,360,420,540,600,660,720,840,900,960,1020,1080,1140,1260,1320,1380,1440,1500,1620]},{"id":34,"lineId":4,"direction":"Гробищен парк-Депо","name":"Гробищен парк-Депо","begin":1682629200,"end":0,"length":14352,"stopIds":[41592,41663,41809,41574,41724,41631,41629,41674,41628,41541,41616,41528,41618,41564,41594,41787,41711,41568,41754,41566,41632,41695,41789,41763,41570,41639,41534,41713,41759,41725,41585,41579,41654,41641,41595],"stopOffsets":[0,60,120,180,300,360,420,540,600,660,780,840,960,1080,1200,1320,1380,1440,1560,1680,1800,1860,1920,2040,2100,2160,2220,2280,2340,2400,2460,2520,2640,2700,2760]},{"id":54,"lineId":10,"direction":"Добротица-Рилци","name":"Добротица-Рилци","begin":1691960400,"end":0,"length":13838,"stopIds":[41724,41631,41629,41541,41805,41620,41666,41820,41653,41537,41753,41700,41681,41665,41773,41576,41571,41658,41623,41815,41709,41803,41829,41752,41766,41812,41816,41729,41690],"stopOffsets":[0,60,120,180,240,300,360,370,480,540,600,720,840,900,960,1020,1080,1140,1200,1260,1320,1440,1500,1620,1740,1860,1920,2040,2100]},{"id":36,"lineId":13,"direction":"Гробищен парк-Депо","name":"Гробищен парк-Депо","begin":1682629200,"end":0,"length":9814,"stopIds":[41592,41663,41809,41574,41747,41750,41806,41681,41665,41773,41571,41731,41589,41627,41715,41547,41570,41639,41534,41713,41759,41725,41585,41579,41654,41595],"stopOffsets":[0,60,120,180,300,360,480,600,720,780,900,960,1020,1080,1140,1200,1260,1320,1380,1440,1500,1560,1620,1680,1740,1800]}]'

function stopNameAndNumById {
    echo $stopsData | jq -r --arg id "$1" '.[] | select(.id == ($id | tonumber)) | "\(.number),\(.name)"'
}

function collectLinesDesc {
    if [ -z "$linesDesc" ]; then
        linesDesc='[{"id":13,"kind":"BUS","number":"4а","name":"Линия 4A","nightly":false,"routeIds":[35,36],"type":"URBAN","carrier":"X"}]'
    fi
}

function linesFromStopId {
    IFS=', ' read -ra id_arr <<< "$1"
    i=true

    for id in "${id_arr[@]}"; do
        stopNumName=$(stopNameAndNumById "$id")
        for row in $(echo "$stopSchedule" | jq -c -r '.[] | {lineId, remainingTime, routeId}'); do
            lineId=$(echo "$row" | jq -r '.lineId')
            routeId=$(echo "$row" | jq -r '.routeId')
            remainingTime=$(echo "$row" | jq -r '.remainingTime[0]')
            routeName=$(echo "$routesData" | jq -r '.[] | select(.id == '$routeId') | .name')
            remainingTimeInMinutes=$((remainingTime / 60))
            key=$lineId
            while [[ -n "${result[$key]}" ]]; do
                key="${key}_"
            done
            result["$key"]="$remainingTimeInMinutes,$routeName"
        done
        [ $i = true ] && i=false || echo
        echo -e "Спирка $(cut -d',' -f2 <<< $stopNumName) ($(cut -d',' -f1 <<< $stopNumName))\n"
        for key in "${!result[@]}"; do
            newKey="$key"
            if [[ $key == *_ ]]; then
                newKey="${key%_}"
            fi
            IFS=',' read -ra values <<< "${result[$key]}"
            if [ $newKey -gt "12" ]; then
                collectLinesDesc
                newKey=$(echo $linesDesc | jq -r --arg id "$newKey" '.[] | select(.id == ($id | tonumber)) | .number' | awk '{ print toupper($0) }')
            fi
            echo "Линия $newKey (${values[1]}) - ${values[0]} минути"
        done
        result=()
    done
}

linesFromStopId "41571"
```

I'm looking for an elegant way to sort the keys of the `$result` associative array in an ascending order in memory, not when i'm printing the data to the output.

Before the `while [[ -n "${result[$key]}" ]]; do` loop, it is guaranteed that the keys of the array contain only numbers (one or two digits long).

`collectLinesDesc` collects the description of the bus lines from a RESTful API if we haven't already collected them before.

The current output of the minimal working example will be:

```
Спирка МБАЛ Добрич (44)

Линия 8 (Практикер-Депо) - 0 м.
Линия 8 (Депо-Практикер) - 0 м.
Линия 6 (Балик-Дружба-Център) - 0 м.
Линия 2 (Балик-Старт) - 0 м.
Линия 1 (АПК-Строител) - 0 м.
Линия 2 (Старт-Балик) - 0 м.
Линия 12 (Липите-Център) - 0 м.
Линия 4А (Гробищен парк-Депо) - 0 м.
Линия 10 (Добротица-Рилци) - 0 м.
```

Expected output (the number after "Линия" sorted in ascending order):

```
Спирка МБАЛ Добрич (44)

Линия 1 (Практикер-Депо) - 0 м.
Линия 2 (Депо-Практикер) - 0 м.
Линия 2 (Балик-Дружба-Център) - 0 м.
Линия 6 (Балик-Старт) - 0 м.
Линия 8 (АПК-Строител) - 0 м.
Линия 8 (Старт-Балик) - 0 м.
Линия 10 (Липите-Център) - 0 м.
Линия 12 (Гробищен парк-Депо) - 0 м.
Линия 4A (Добротица-Рилци) - 0 м.
```

*("4A" here is a display value, in the array it will be a number bigger than 12, so it will always be last when sorted in ascending order, so the logic remains consistent with the display logic)*

One way i can think of is to make `jq` output the data from the JSON ordered by `lineId`, and then use a second indexed array to keep the order of the entries, then using that indexed array as a key for the associative aray `$result` when i iterate through it in  the loop that finally outputs the data, but is there a nicer / shorter / simpler way to achieve the same in Bash?

Comment: I'm not sure if this counts as "more elegant", but since you know that your keys are integers in a small range (0–99), one option would be to iterate using `for key in {0..99}`, and then skipping any nonexistent keys.

Comment: (Note: I posted that as a comment rather than an answer because I'm on a smartphone right now and couldn't read your code well enough to see if that would work. If anyone wants to vet that and make an answer out of it, please feel free!)

Comment: It looks like you could probably replace most/all of that with a single `jq` invocation. Perhaps you could post a runnable example (sample curl response along with the end result) (What does `collectLinesDesc` do?)

Comment: The question is updated, sorry for not providing all the info initially. You can commented out / remove the ```$routeName``` because of the missing ```$routesData``` and it should be runnable with the samples.

Comment: so .... the sorted data consists of ordering the 2nd column but leaving the 3rd column (in parens) as is (eg, the only difference in the 1st row is the 2nd column - `Линия 8 (Практикер-Депо)` (before) vs `Линия 1 (Практикер-Депо)` (after))? also, the trailing number (`0 м.` in this case) will always be `0 м.` or could it differ? and if it could differ, does it get moved/sorted along with the 2nd column, or does it also stay where it is (as with the 3rd column)?

Comment: Correct. "0 м." stays at the place it is, always, but could change value, i.e. 5 м. or 12 м. or 105 м. or any other number (up to 4 digits long) depending on the data in the ```remainingTime[]``` array. I will also add sample for ```$linesDesc``` in the question.

Comment: How the function `stopNameAndNumById` defined? Besides the sample of `$linesDesc` is invalid around `"carrier":"X},`. Please post minimal but complete
executable code.

Comment: The question was updated with a minimal working example of the script. Bash version used on my end - 5.2.15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the keys are defined to be small integers, you could trivially keep `result` (partially) ordered by using `-a` instead of `-A`, since indexed arrays are traversed by increasing numerical index.

Store the key as a scaled-up value (eg. multiply by 1000). Whenever there is a collision, instead of appending `_`, add 1.

When using the keys later, scale back down (eg. divide by 1000). Since bash uses integer arithmetic, this will drop any fractional part, giving the original pre-collision key.

For example:

```
# declare -A result
declare -a result
# ...
            # key=$lineId
            (( key = lineId*1000 ))
            while [[ -n "${result[$key]}" ]]; do
                # key="${key}_"
                (( key++ ))
            done
# ...
        for key in "${!result[@]}"; do
            # newKey="$key"
            # if [[ $key == *_ ]]; then
            #    newKey="${key%_}"
            # fi
            (( newKey = key/1000 ))
# ...
```

but this will produce different output from what was requested:

```
Спирка МБАЛ Добрич (44)

Линия 1 (АПК-Строител) - 57 минути
Линия 2 (Балик-Старт) - 23 минути
Линия 2 (Старт-Балик) - 50 минути
Линия 6 (Балик-Дружба-Център) - 51 минути
Линия 8 (Депо-Практикер) - 8 минути
Линия 8 (Практикер-Депо) - 36 минути
Линия 10 (Добротица-Рилци) - 49 минути
Линия 12 (Липите-Център) - 26 минути
Линия 4А (Гробищен парк-Депо) - 53 минути
```

It is very unclear why you expect that sorting the keys will change the values stored in the array.

---

The original code looks as though it may be buggy in the case where there is more than one collision (eg. consider what happens if you replace `6` with `8` in the data).

Comment: That is a nice approach and works well, the oddity you have discovered is just a problem with the sample data. Using the live data from the API, it is fine - tested and confirmed. It would be great if you could add a short explanation of the changes you have made compared to the original code because i believe it would be useful for anyone who may stumble about this question later.

Answer (score 2):

As your real JSON data comes from several `curl` calls, it may require some restructuring, but perhaps this is still a useful example:

As a potential alternative to running [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) individually on each id and using `select(.id == ...)` you could combine the records using `INDEX()` and `JOIN()`

- [Understanding jq JOIN()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71106595/understanding-jq-join)

```bash
stopSchedule='...'
stopsData='...'
routesData='...'
linesDesc='...'

jq -n -r \
\
  --argjson stopsData    "$stopsData"    \
  --argjson stopSchedule "$stopSchedule" \
  --argjson routesData   "$routesData"   \
  --argjson linesDesc    "$linesDesc"    \
'
[
   # extract lines.number and combine records based on lines.id == stop.lineId
   # create result with { routeId: {...} } shape in order to JOIN with routesData
   JOIN( 
      INDEX($linesDesc[] | {id, number}; .id);
      $stopSchedule[] | {lineId, routeId, remainingTime};
      .lineId | tostring; 
      . as [$stop, $line] | {($stop.routeId | tostring): add} 
   ) as $stopSchedule
   | 
   # extract route.name and combine records based on stop.id == route.id
   JOIN( 
      $stopSchedule; 
      $routesData[] | {id, name}; 
      .id | tostring; 
      add
   )
   | .remainingTime = ((.remainingTime[0] // 0) / 60 | floor)
]
| sort_by(.lineId)[]
| select(.lineId) # skip {"lineId": null}
| "Линия \(if .lineId > 12 then .number else .lineId end) (\(.name)) - \(.remainingTime) минути"
'
```

```
Линия 1 (АПК-Строител) - 57 минути
Линия 2 (Балик-Старт) - 23 минути
Линия 2 (Старт-Балик) - 50 минути
Линия 6 (Балик-Дружба-Център) - 51 минути
Линия 8 (Депо-Практикер) - 8 минути
Линия 8 (Практикер-Депо) - 36 минути
Линия 10 (Добротица-Рилци) - 49 минути
Линия 12 (Липите-Център) - 26 минути
Линия 4а (Гробищен парк-Депо) - 53 минути
```

The only missing piece being `toupper` ([unfortunately, unicode `upcase` did not make it into `1.7`](https://github.com/jqlang/jq/pull/2547))

You can however output the id/number, name, time and print the final string with shell/awk.