# json jq add an object to an existing array at the bottom of JSON

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to get some infos from `lscpu` and `sensors` in `bash` with `jq`:

```
jq -s 'add' \
    <(LC_NUMERIC=C sensors -j coretemp-isa-0000) \
    <(LC_NUMERIC=C lscpu -J -e=cpu,mhz)
```

here's what I get:

```
{
  "coretemp-isa-0000": {
    "Adapter": "ISA adapter",
    "Package id 0": {
      "temp1_input": 32.000,
      "temp1_max": 80.000,
      "temp1_crit": 99.000,
      "temp1_crit_alarm": 0.000
    },
    "Core 0": {
      "temp2_input": 32.000,
      "temp2_max": 80.000,
      "temp2_crit": 99.000,
      "temp2_crit_alarm": 0.000
    },
    "Core 1": {
      "temp3_input": 22.000,
      "temp3_max": 80.000,
      "temp3_crit": 99.000,
      "temp3_crit_alarm": 0.000
    },
    "Core 2": {
      "temp4_input": 31.000,
      "temp4_max": 80.000,
      "temp4_crit": 99.000,
      "temp4_crit_alarm": 0.000
    },
    "Core 3": {
      "temp5_input": 28.000,
      "temp5_max": 80.000,
      "temp5_crit": 99.000,
      "temp5_crit_alarm": 0.000
    }
  },
  "cpus": [
    {
      "cpu": 0,
      "mhz": 2997.8560
    },
    {
      "cpu": 1,
      "mhz": 3191.4871
    },
    {
      "cpu": 2,
      "mhz": 2948.6250
    },
    {
      "cpu": 3,
      "mhz": 1600.0000
    }
  ]
}
```

and what I want is:

```
0 2997 32
1 3191 22
2 2948 31
3 1600 28
```

I come to this:

```
#!/bin/bash

filtre='add
    |(.["coretemp-isa-0000"]
    |keys[] as $core
    |select($core|test("^Core [0-9]$"))
    |($core|ltrimstr("Core ")) as $id
    |.[$core]
    |keys[] as $temp
    |select($temp|test("temp[0-9]_input"))
    |.cpus[$id|tonumber] += {"temp":.[$temp]}),.cpus'

jq -rs "$filtre" \
    <(LC_NUMERIC=C sensors -j coretemp-isa-0000) \
    <(LC_NUMERIC=C lscpu -J -e=cpu,mhz)
```

but it doesn't do what I want : it only feeds a `.cpus` array in each `$core`, and leaves the `.cpus` I want to be changed unchanged.

Comment: Please limit your example to a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for the [`JOIN` operator](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#sql-style-operators):

```bash
filtre='
  JOIN(
    ."coretemp-isa-0000"; input.cpus[]; "Core \(.cpu)"; [first.cpu, first.mhz, (
      last | to_entries[] | select(.key | endswith("_input")).value
    ) | trunc]
  ) | join(" ")
'

jq -r "$filtre" <(…sensors…) <(…lscpu…)
```

```
0 2997 32
1 3191 22
2 2948 31
3 1600 28
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/m54vyrMC-CR)

Comment: `JOIN($idx; stream; idx_expr; join_expr)`
I don't understand all the filters in the join_expr part yet, but I'll work on it.

thanks a lot.

Comment: @daPeach Here's a step-by-step example how to use `JOIN`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71107203/2158479

Comment: there's something I might be missing...
I'm trying to join `ip -j -4 a` and `ip -j -4 l` like this: `jq -r 'input as $left|. as $right|JOIN( INDEX($right[];.ifindex) ; $left[] ; .ifindex ; . )' <(ip -4 -j a ) <(ip -4 -j l )`
but I get the error : jq: error (at /dev/fd/62:1): Cannot index object with number

Comment: @daPeach You're missing that object fields must be strings. The `.ifindex` values in both inputs are numbers. While `INDEX` will convert it automatically, `JOIN` won't. `tostring` would be one option to convert it: `jq 'JOIN(INDEX(.ifindex); input[]; .ifindex | tostring; .)' <(ip -4 -j a) <(ip -4 -j l)`

Comment: @daPeach Alternatively, instead of `.ifindex`, you could match on the `.ifname` field, which should also be unique and is already a string. Apart from that, also try out the `-d` option which could already enhance the output of `ip` to what you might be after: `ip -4 -j -d a`.

Comment: I tried different things with tostring without success
thank you
but I didn't try .ifname, thanks again.

Comment: what if "tables" are not  "symetric" ? for example, when I start an lxc virtual machine, it creates a link that has no address (`ip l` shows a link name "vethXXX..." that is not in `ip a`'s output). This could happen with any inputs.

Comment: @daPeach Following my [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71107203/2158479) from above, you'd find that "an unsuccessful lookup would yield null on the right side". The lookup table is the first argument provided to `JOIN` (the one you'd use `INDEX` on to make it an "indexed" object). The output always follows (and matches on the left side) the input stream (which is provided as second argument to `JOIN/4` or `JOIN/3`, or as input to `JOIN/2`).

Comment: ok! I saw the null, and I thought that was due to JOIN, but that's only the fourth part (the "select") that causes the error. Thank you.